# MemoryError using Nginx, uWSGI, and web.py

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, web.py, mdm

I've got a python Apple MDM server and I'm trying to convert it from being run from a command line process to being hosted using Nginx and uWSGI. I'm using web.py for routing. Everything is running smoothly for the most aprt. I've got what I believe to be a good basic configuration for both Nginx and uWSGI, but this morning after running it for less than 24 hours I'm getting this error on every other request the server receives. There's plenty of memory availble and I'm using the 64 bit version of python.

EDIT1: SSL is talking on port 8080 because there's a load balancer in front of it routing SSL traffic to that port.

EDIT2: I've changed the processes setting in uWSGI from 3 to 1 to see if that's the issue.

EDIT3: This was a fresh box from AWS. Installed my server and it's dependencies, nginx, and uWSGI. I had trouble with running uWSGI as a service and installed and uninstalled the `aptitude` and `pip` versions of it before I eventually got the `pip` version running with `systemd`. That's how it's running now and it's gracefully stopping, starting, and restarting.

```
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 565, in processor
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 77, in reload_mapping
MemoryError
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] 
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 566, in processor
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in <lambda>
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 246, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 477, in internalerror
MemoryError
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] 
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 581, in processor
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in <lambda>
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 246, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 477, in internalerror
MemoryError
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] 
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 566, in processor
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in <lambda>
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 246, in process
  File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 477, in internalerror
MemoryError
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] 
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]   File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 279, in wsgi
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]     [ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] result = self.handle_with_processors()
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]   File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 249, in handle_with_processors
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]     [ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] return process(self.processors)
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]   File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 246, in process
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]     [ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] raise self.internalerror()
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]   File "/path/to/app/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 477, in internalerror
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]     [ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] import debugerror
[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ] MemoryError[ Tue Jun 14 2016 10:29:22 ]
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

site-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        root /path/to/app/;
    }

    location / {
        include   uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
server {
    listen   8080;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /path/to/app/certs/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /path/to/app/certs/ssl.key;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        root /path/to/app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include   uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /path/to/app/;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /path/to/app/virtualenv/;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT server;
    }
}
```

uWSGI ini

```
home = /path/to/app/virtualenv/
chdir = /path/to/app/
module = server:application
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
rlogdate =  [ %%a %%b %%d %%Y %%H:%%M:%%S ]
logformat = %(method) %(status) %(addr)  %(uri) wid: %(wid) 
log-encoder = format ${strftime:[ %%a %%b %%d %%Y %%H:%%M:%%S ]} ${msgnl}
gid = ubuntu
uid = ubuntu
vhost = false 
socket = 127.0.0.1:9000
master = true
processes = 3
harakiri = 20
limit-as = 128
memory-report
no-orphans
```

I've been told I have a fairly bad case of Accidental SysAdmin Syndrome, so any and all help/advice is appreciated. Just for good measure here's the output of `proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:        7657772 kB
MemFree:         5971508 kB
MemAvailable:    7145084 kB
Buffers:          225528 kB
Cached:           900756 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1142912 kB
Inactive:         358288 kB
Active(anon):     380568 kB
Inactive(anon):    11956 kB
Active(file):     762344 kB
Inactive(file):   346332 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                48 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        375008 kB
Mapped:            55840 kB
Shmem:             17616 kB
Slab:             129300 kB
SReclaimable:     106084 kB
SUnreclaim:        23216 kB
KernelStack:        3120 kB
PageTables:         6672 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3828884 kB
Committed_AS:     602572 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    143360 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       71680 kB
DirectMap2M:     7923712 kB
```

Comment: Really mysterious. 64-bit OS and python, harakiri enabled. ulimit?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ulimit, but I read a little bit about it and ran the command. It returned `unlimited`. So yeah, I haven't limited the resources available or anything. Adding another edit with a bit more possibly relevant information.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. You don't have `max-requests` set in your uWSGI .ini. Thus, your python interpreters live forever and might accumulate garbage. Try settings it to something, e.g. 5000 and, hopefully, leakage will stop.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll test for a couple days and see if I get the error again. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Yup that seems to be it, @Bob. I've left it running for a while, and worker 3 is getting the error again, 1 and 2 aren't. I have metrics turned on now, and worker 3 is above 4400 requests while the other two are below 1000. max-requests not being set would seem to be the issue, though it looks like I'll have to set it for somewhere around 3500 ~ 4000 instead of the suggested 5000. At least in my dev environment. The prod server has more resources. If you'll post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `max-requests` set in your uWSGI .ini. Thus, your python interpreters live forever and might accumulate garbage. Try settings it to something, e.g. 5000 and, hopefully, leakage will stop.

If you get more statistical results in future and they disprove `max-requests` version, share them, please. Good luck, James Fitter.